# How to delete an entry from html tabel with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm searching for the solution to delete an entry from a existing html table in my view.

The following parts have I implemented at the moment:

The controller:

```
def destroy_user_role
 TopicPremission.find(params[:role_id]).destroy if request.post?
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html 
   format.js
 end
end
```

The view(_save_role.html.erb):

```
<table class="list user_roles">
 <tr>
  <th><%= User %></th>
  <th><%= Role %></th>
  <th style="width:15%"></th>  
 </tr>
 <% @actual_roles.each do |role| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= value = @users.detect{|u| u.id == role.user_id} 
       value.firstname + " " + value.lastname %></td> 

  <% if role.level == 1 %>
    <td><%= "READ" %></td>
  <% elsif role.level == 2 %>
    <td><%= "READ/WRITE" %></td>
  <% end %>   

  <td><%= link_to "Destroy", {controller: "topics" , action: "destroy_user_role", :role_id => role.id , :id => params[:id]},  :remote => true,:method => :post ,  class: "icon icon-del" %></td>    
 <% end %>
</table>
```

The .js.erb:

```
$('table.user_roles').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'save_role') %>')
```

With this code I get always the 500 Error, but I can't find the failure. Hope somebody can help me!

Comment: check the console what error you are getting.

Comment: firstly remove format.html from the method destroy_user_role and assign a unique id to your list html table.

Comment: K, I remove "format.html" in my controller and add the id, additionally i add "@user" and "@actual_roles" at my controller. Now it delete's the entry but. But the table look something strange after the removal from the entry. He builds somehow a tabel across the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
#_save_role.html.erb
<% @actual_roles.each do |role| %>
  <tr id="<%= role.id %>">
     <td>
        <%= value = @users.detect{|u| u.id == role.user_id} %>
        <%= value.firstname + " " + value.lastname %>
     </td> 
     <td>
        <% permission = (role.level == "2") ? "/WRITE" : "" %>
        <%= "READ#{permission}" %>
     </td>
     <td>
      <%= link_to "Destroy", {controller: "topics" , action: "destroy_user_role", :role_id => role.id , :id => params[:id]},  :remote => true,:method => :post ,  class: "icon icon-del" %>
     </td> 
  </tr>   
<% end %>


#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
respond_to :html, :js

def destroy_user_role
 @role = TopicPremission.find(params[:role_id])
 @id = @role.id

 @role.destroy if request.post?
 respond_with @id #-> Could send @role.id, but it may be deleted
end 

#app/views/controller/destroy_user_role.js.erb
$('<%=j "##{@id}" %>').fadeOut(150, function(){
     $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Wow thx, still one question, if i added before an entry with .append command and I will delete this entry, it still exists in the view after i press the delete link. What can be the problem here?